# Assign values to arrays in structs

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, struct

I am using a struct that, within it, it has an array of pointers to other structs of the same type. How do I assign that array at design time to have multiple elements?

Example:

```
struct structx {
int value;
structx *pChild[];
};

void funcY(hasChild*, int);

struct structx noChild = { 1, NULL };

struct structx otherNoChild = { 2, NULL };

struct structx childHaver = {
3,
&noChild
};

struct structx parent = {
4,
&childHaver
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
funcY(&parent, 0);

cout << endl;

funcY(&childHaver, 0);

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void funcY(hasChild* child, int childPosition)
{
if (child->pChild[0] != NULL)
{
    funcY(child->pChild[childPosition], childPosition);
}
cout << child->value << endl;
}
```

This code is for C++ in visual studio 2008.

When I use this code, it works just fine, and prints 1, 3, 4.

However, if I try to put multiple addresses into the struct, like so:

```
struct structx parent = {
4,
(&childHaver, &noChild)
};
```

It despite sending in position 0, it will select &noChild, which should be the next position in the array.

Is there a special way to do this in the syntax that I'm missing?

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use an array of pointers to `structx`? Can you use `std::vector<struct*>` instead?

Comment: `(&childHaver, &noChild)` is using the comma operator, not passing multiple things. And that struct hack isn't valid C++.

Comment: Vectors might work, but it depends on my Head of Development. He doesn't like them. What's the syntax for passing multiple things?

Comment: you don't have any arrays of structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the curly braces for initializing the array of structs.

```
struct structx parent = {
4,
{&childHaver, &noChild}
};
```